# Docker mysql official image

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

In this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/b4b7c8eea0690d0406a5ffc2d3404c8c42457a2d/5.7/Dockerfile), a "mysql" user is created but there is no "USER mysql" instruction. So why, when you run the image without "-u" or "--user" mysqld is running as "mysql" and not as "root" ?

Comment: [because suid, may be](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115873/using-suid-bit-to-drop-privileges/115877#115877)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ probably

Comment: It could have been suid but it's not, no suid on mysqld. And "docker" and "dockerfile" are valid tags for SO so I don't think it's offtopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Dockerfile and `docker-entrypoint.sh` file ([here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/b4b7c8eea0690d0406a5ffc2d3404c8c42457a2d/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L67)), you can see that the container will execute (unless you provide a differenct command)

```
docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld
```

And in that script, it will be executed as

```
exec gosu mysql "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
```

(`$@` is the arguments of that script, which are `mysqld` only in this case)